# Recognize the tablets position

Tags: android

I want to build a system where a tablet moves along a 1,5 meter rail with 10 stations. The user dan move the tablet aloong the rail from one station to another. Therefor a question:

What way is it possible that the app recognizes: "Tablet has reached positon #10". The acceleration sensor cannot solve this. I thought of a NFC terminal on each station but this is complicated and expensive.

Do you have any ideas how the tablet can recognize it has moved? Is there by the way a possibility to suppres the home and power button?

Thanks, best regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it using the magnetic sensor and putting magnets on each station.
Or you can use the camera to detect QRCodes or colored squares which will be placed on each station.

You can't suppress the effect of the Home button.
For the Power button, try to intercept it overriding the method `onKeyEvent`.

Comment: The power button is not delivered to apps.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought of a NFC terminal on each station but this is complicated and expensive.

NFC tags cost well under 1 USD apiece. Assuming your tablets are NFC-capable, those should work, assuming you can position the tags in the proper spot, so that when the tablet is in the right place, the tag is underneath the place where the NFC antenna is on the tablet.

> Do you have any ideas how the tablet can recognize it has moved?

NFC is likely to be the simplest and least-expensive option.

> Is there by the way a possibility to suppres the home and power button?

Download the Android source code, modify it as you see fit, compile the results into a ROM mod, and install that on the tablets.